# How to obtain ManagedThreadId's and ProcessThreadId's of a .Net-process correctly assigned to each other?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, clr

As you all know, and as the VS-/ C# documentation states as well, there is no relation between the ThreadId's of the CLR on the one hand (ManagedThreadId) and those of the underlying process (ProcessThreadId) on the other hand, therefore no possibility being at hand to use one information in order to get the other.

Nonetheless, the VS-/C# IDE seems to be capable of bringing about *exactly that*, f. i. in it's ThreadDebugging-Window, where any of the current application's threads with their respective ManagedThreadIds are shown correctly assigned to their process-based counterparts.

Does anyone have an idea which way could be gone to achieve sth. similar programmatically (or an idea of how to get the corresponding information the CLR is hiding from the user)? Reflection offered no way, and up to now I didn't find a P/Invoke / API function being suitable to that end either.

Thanks & many greets

Heinzi

Comment: The CLR provides a back-door into its internals.  Called the DAC, Data Access Component.  The kind of back-door that tooling like debuggers and profilers need to get their job done.  It does not hide the OS thread id.  https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/ClrThread.cs#L134  It is not clear if this library is what you need to do what you want to do, beware that it is a big gun.

Comment: If you can live with the small(?) chance that you encounter a CLR host that actually does not map managed and native threads 1:1, you could simply use [`AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/appdomain.cs,9821ecd7311cecdb) (or P/Invoke `GetCurrentThreadId` directly). It's not clean and the function has been marked `Obsolote` for the reasons you state, but depending on your needs it might be OK.